# Sharing of answers in online puzzle/treasure hunt games?

Tags: puzzle-creation, treasure-hunt

I'm planning to organize a Online treasure hunt game for the students of my institution. The idea is very simple.

You register and login. You start at Level 1. You'll be given a question/clue/image and you have to input the right answer to move on to the next level. You can only get to the current level if you've solved the previous level. I've developed the tech required for this from scratch.

There is a qualifying round currently going on for this event. However, I've noticed that the players are sharing answers with each other. I came to this conclusion because:

1. When a person solves a level, then that level gets solved by a lot of people in a very short amount of time.
2. I'm logging the timestamp and the input of every user. When someone solves a question, another one (possibly his friend) also solves the same level. This happens for multiple levels.
3. One person admitted to sharing answers.

I've been scratching my brain on how to solve this issue. One such idea that I thought of from the beginning was to hide the leaderboard. So the players don't know who reached which level and their current position.

This is proving to be difficult because all the levels has to be same for everyone, hence everyone's answers being same.

Is there any way I can have unique answers for each user while keeping the question same? Or is there a way I can reduce people sharing their answers? If there is something you think of please let me know.

Thank You!

Comment: Is this website open to the public? If so, could someone provide the link :)

Comment: @WilliamPennanti Sorry for the late reply. I was busy managing the website. The first round has ended and I'm in between rounds. it is not quite open to the public, but you can give it a shot if you want. The URL is http://expendentine.rabeeh.me
While registering, make sure you give a fake 10 digit phone no. with no hyphens or spaces. Email can also be fake. You won't be able to play right after you register and login. Just leave your username here as a comment and I will activate your account.
P.S: I didn't make the questions. A friend did. It might be too easy for experts. ;)

Comment: Is it a British website? I am having a slight trouble when it asks for a phone number. Would you be able to provide a possible fake phone number for whichever country it is based in. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: It is an Indian Website. I told right? Just use any 10 digit number. 9999999999.

Comment: I have activated your account. You should be free to login and play. Just don't post your answers anywhere. Contests are going on. There are 17 levels as of now. The theme for the first 10 levels are 'Around the World' and from level 11-17, the theme is a country which you should figure out. Pretty easy. Have fun. Do give your feedback if possible.

Answer (score 7):

This doesn't completely solve your problem, but might help a little.

You could design puzzles whose method of solving is consistently the same, but whose exact answer depends on the specific information given when the problem is displayed. Then you could randomize the input such that each time a given puzzle is displayed, the exact content of the puzzle varies slightly, thus requiring a different correct answer.

Students can still share the method they used with each other, but at least all students would have to work through each problem to obtain a solution, rather than just type in an answer they were told by somebody else.

As an extra step, you could also add in a penalty if, say, a student types in an answer which is correct for a version of the problem different from their own and for which there is no conceivable way they could have gotten that answer other than being told by someone else. Then let the students know that such a penalty is in effect, to encourage them to be more honest.

Comment: Thank you for this. I had actually thought about adding such a penalty, but never really know how to unless I can make different answers for different people. I'll keep this in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the way which  might help you :-

You can create same question in all level with some random twist i.e : changing the numbers, by changing or twisting the question ,changing clues etc

You can create software that will restrict user to use internet ... I don't know if you have created desktop app or Mobile app ..but this will restrict student from searching answer on internet or using any medium like whatsapp n all to share the answers

I remember I have given an aptitude test where all student where sitting nearby but all where getting random question like at one time no two student were given same  question to answer.

Also give time limit for each question so that student will be buzy in solving there own question instead of sharing answers with others.

Lastly, you might be knowing every student capabilities if they can solve such question or not so this will also help you to find more deserving candidate.

Comment: The thing is, the clues are given in such a way that they have to use the internet to find the location. Otherwise, I could make them to connect via a VPN to my server and make them play there. I will have to introduce some randomness to their questions. Thanks.